# GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged, Getting error for Katalon Studio Linux (Beta GUI)

Tags: ubuntu, gtk, katalon-studio

I am trying to install Katalon Studio on my ubuntu in GUI mode. Unfortunately, it's giving the following error.

I run the file `./katalon`

**Got this error**

> (Katalon Studio:1136): GLib-CRITICAL **: 11:55:34.629: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed
>
> (Katalon Studio:1136): GLib-CRITICAL **: 11:55:34.641: Gtk-Message: 11:55:35.143: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.

**My current Java version is**

```
openjdk version "11" 2018-09-25
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11+24-Ubuntu-118.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11+24-Ubuntu-118.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

**My Ubuntu version is:**

```
Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
```

Any type of suggestion or help will be really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could try with openjdk 1.8